# Pytorch NN Training issue: Loss of NN does not decrase

Tags: pytorch, classification

I want to classify random Instagram images as "image has a dog" or "image has not a dog".
To train my NN to classify dogs I want to use the Stanford Dogs Dataset, so I have about 20.000 training images of different dogs with different breeds.

But while training my NN the loss does not decrease, I checked that with different learning rates and with or without dropout layers.

Can anyone give tips or does anyone see bugs in the following code?:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
import os
import random
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn

TRAINDATAPATH = 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/train/'
TESTDATAPATH = 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/#apfel/'

"""normalize = transforms.Normalize(
   mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
   std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
)"""
normalize = transforms.Normalize(
   mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
   std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
)
transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256),
                                 transforms.CenterCrop(256),
                                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 normalize])

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
train_data_list = []
target_list = []
train_data = []

batch_size = 1

files = listdir(TRAINDATAPATH)

for i in range(len(listdir(TRAINDATAPATH))):
    try:
        f = random.choice(files)
        files.remove(f)
        img = Image.open(TRAINDATAPATH + f)
        img_tensor = transforms(img) # (3,256,256)
        train_data_list.append(img_tensor)
        isObj = 1 if 'obj' in f else 0
        isNotObj = 0 if 'obj' in f else 1
        target = [isObj, isNotObj]

        target_list.append(target)
        if len(train_data_list) >= 1:
            train_data.append((torch.stack(train_data_list), target_list))
            train_data_list = []
            target_list = []
            print('Loaded batch ', int(len(train_data)/batch_size), 'of ', int(len(listdir(TRAINDATAPATH))/batch_size))
            print('Percentage Done: ', 100*int(len(train_data)/batch_size)/int(len(listdir(TRAINDATAPATH))/batch_size), '%')
    except Exception:
        print("Error occured but ignored")
        print(str(Exception))
        continue

class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 12, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 18, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(18, 24, kernel_size=5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3456, 1000)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x,2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = x.view(-1,3456)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return torch.sigmoid(x)

model = Netz()
model.to(torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"))

optimizer = optim.Adadelta(model.parameters(), lr=10)
def train(epoch):
    global model

    model.train()
    batch_idx = 0
    for data, target in train_data:
        batch_idx += 1
        data = data.to(torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"))
        target = torch.Tensor(target).to(torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"))
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output = model(data)

        criterion = F.binary_cross_entropy
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        print('Train Epoch: '+ str(epoch) + '\tLoss: ' + str(loss.data.item()) )


def test():
    global model

    model.eval()
    files = listdir(TESTDATAPATH)
    f = random.choice(files)
    img = Image.open(TESTDATAPATH + f)
    img_eval_tensor = transforms(img)
    img_eval_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
    data = Variable(img_eval_tensor.to(torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")) )
    out = model(data)
    string_prediction = str(out.data.max(0, keepdim=True)[1])
    print(string_prediction[9:10])

for epoch in range(1,4):
    train(epoch)
i = 100
while i > 0:
    test()
    i -= 1
```

In the TRAINDATAPATH are thousands of Dog images with the filename "obj_XXX.jpg" and some other images WITHOUT dogs with other filenames don't including "obj".

In the TESTDATAPATH are just random images, some with dogs, some without. 
The NN classifies them all as "not including dogs" or "0" which is incorrect.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: You say you tried different learning rates, in what range? A learning rate of 10 is not only far too high, but a learning rate greater than 1 makes it impossible to converge. Learning rates should usually be around 0.01 or 0.001.

Comment: I tried learningrates between .001 and 100.

Comment: Okay, then maybe try a different optimiser such as [`optim.SGD`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.SGD) or [`optim.AdamW`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.AdamW), with a learning rate of 0.001.

Comment: And you dont see any major mistakes? It's one of my first pytorch projects...

Comment: With the AdamW optimizer the loss values still just bounce between 0.7 and 0.6! With the SGD optimizer, the loss bounces between 1.1 and 0.08, it's still not decreasing overall.  :( All tested with lr=0.001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a binary classification but you are using two classes:

```py
isObj = 1 if 'obj' in f else 0
isNotObj = 0 if 'obj' in f else 1
target = [isObj, isNotObj]
```

In the binary case, it should be a single class, where 1 means it is a dog, and 0 means it is not. You are already doing it, but twice. You can remove the `isNotObj` entirely and only keep the `isObj`.

You need to adapt the model accordingly, such that it only predicts the `isObj`, therefore `fc2` should only have 1 class as output:

```py
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1000, 1)
```

In the testing phase you need to make a prediction based on a single class, which can be seen as the *probability of being a dog*. Then you set a threshold for which you consider the model to be confident enough that it's actually a dog. To make it balanced, the threshold is 0.5, so everything above that is a dog and everything below it is not. This can easily be achieved with [`torch.round`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.round):

```py
# Size: [batch_size, 1]
out = model(data)
predictions = torch.round(out)
# Get rid of the singular dimension
# To get size: [batch_size]
predictions = predictions.squeeze(1)
```

Besides that, the learning rate of 10 is astronomically high, and a learning rate greater than 1 makes it impossible to converge. A more appropriate learning rate is around 0.01 or 0.001.

And on side note, since you are new to PyTorch: Please don't use [`Variable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated), it was deprecated with PyTorch 0.4.0, which was released over 2 years ago, and all of its functionality has been merged into the tensors.

Comment: Really really thank you. I will try to adapt your tips.